# ServiceController.Stop() fails to stop service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service which I'm trying to stop progrmatically using `ServiceController.Stop()`:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(<ServiceName>);                    
sc.Stop();
sc.Refresh();
```

However, when I see this service in the Services list, its status still remains as "Started". If I call the method `sc.WaitForStatus()` to wait till the status is changed to "Stopped", then this status is never reached.

What's going wrong?

Comment: If you try to stop it from the services list, does that work?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, it stops from the service list if i do it manually.

Comment: Any exceptions? Perhaps a permission issue?

Comment: @leppie: No problem with permissions. Service is running on my local machine.

Comment: Is the service name correct? You might be passing in the display name instead of a service name?

Comment: The status comes from the service itself. If the service doesn't respond (or responds very slowly) to the stop command the status won't change.

Comment: @Richard: When I stop it from service list, it stops quite quickly. Why does it give problem while stopping programmatically? And the service name i am passing to controller is correct too.

Comment: maybe your application is running without "run as administrator" ?

Comment: @All: I think problem was with legacy code. We need some configuration and if it's missing in config file, service should not be started. This validation was done in 'OnStart()' and if it fails to validate, 'ServiceController.Stop()' was called from the OnStart() method itself. I think that's why ServiceController.Stop() was not able to stop the service and I never got the status "Stopped" in 'WaitForStatus()' method call. I changed the logic and now i dont call 'Run()' method if necessary configuration is missing.

Comment: @CSharpLearner: That makes sense. Suggest you write that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Richard: Added my previous comment as an answer since this was the reason why ServiceController.Stop() was failing to stop the service.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem was with legacy code.

We need some configuration and the requirement is if configuration is missing in config file, service should not be started. This validation was done in `OnStart()`. The `ServiceController.Stop()` was called from the `OnStart()` method itself whenever validation fails! I think that's why `ServiceController.Stop()` was not able to stop the service and I never got the status "Stopped" in `WaitForStatus()` method call.

I changed the logic and now i dont call `ServiceBase.Run()` method (which gives call to `OnStart()`) if necessary configuration is missing.

**The legacy code was trying to Stop the service from its Start method!**