# How to stop current service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

What I am trying to do is if a certain condition is met, stop the service.

I can stop a service by

```
 ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("serviceName");
 sc.Stop();
```

Is there a way to stop the current service without passing in the service name?

Comment: What you mean by 'current' service?

Comment: SO I am running a service, the code within the service should cause the service to stop if a particular condition is met.

Comment: you may check this similar post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813948/servicecontroller-stop-fails-to-stop-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/708fb7c4) without parameters.

That should give you a service controller instance that is in the context of the currently running windows service.

Comment: Not sure if it changed since you posted this, but I'm not sure why this comment is marked as the answer. The page you link to states "Initializes a new instance of the ServiceController class that is not associated with a specific service". It does not link to the currently running service.